# Send notification to the client from a web server

Tags: java, client-server, client, send

My setup consists of a Weblogic server that runs various REST services that accepts an HTTP request from a client(an android app), reads data from a MySql database and sends this data as a response to the client.

My requirement is that the client should be notified as soon as the database is updated. I have implemented a "polling" mechanism. The client constantly sends requests and checks for any changes made in the database. However this is not a very efficient mechanism.
Can you please suggest any efficient ways of achieving this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562775/server-side-push?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to use writing a CRON job for observation of Database change.

also, SO has already discussed this topic. refer below link,

[Oracle database to send notification / Invoke a java method on reaching Time specified in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527801/oracle-database-to-send-notification-invoke-a-java-method-on-reaching-time-spe)